# R script "command not found?"

Tags: r, git

I am trying to call an Rscript I created in Rstudio in Git, but it says "Rscript not found"

$ Rscript processDineSafe
bash: Rscript: command not found

I have made sure I am in the right directory, and also that my directory has the file I am trying to call. I also tried to make sure R was added to the path but I wasn't sure exactly how to confirm that.

I am new to git and R so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can see the path in `bash` with `echo $PATH`. In case it is not in the `PATH` you can call `Rscript` by using the full path to it or add it to the `PATH`.

Comment: when I do echo path this is what it looks like:$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin is there a specific command I can use to add Rscript to the path?

Comment: And where is `Rscript` located? When you are where `Rscript` is located, `pwd` gives you the path where you are.